# Define a variable with values between 1 to 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I define a variable x which is true for values form 1 to 100. I have written the code for some idea that how it should work. Please help your valuable time is highly appreciated.

```js
$('.line1').attr("x2", function (d) {
return $('.peak1').attr("x") 
});

$('.line2').attr("x2", function (d) {
return $('.peak2').attr("x")
});

$('.line3').attr("x2", function (d) {
return $('.peak3').attr("x")
});

$('.line4').attr("x2", function (d) {
return $('.peak4').attr("x")
});

$('.line5').attr("x2", function (d) {
return $('.peak5').attr("x")
});

// I want to write this function by defining x value from 1 to 100 so that it would work for every equal value.

var x = 1 to 100;
$('.line'+x).attr("x2", function (d) {
return $('.peak'+x).attr("x")
});
```

Comment: What you want is a for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should make a loop, like this:

```js
for (var i=1; i <= 100; i++) {
  $('.line'+i).attr("x"+i, function (d) {
    return $('.peak'+i).attr("x")
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could provide your HTML then I might give you a working example.

But you just need to loop from x = 1 to 100

```
for (var x = 1; x <= 100; x++){
   $('.line'+x).attr("x2", function (d) {
      return $('.peak'+x).attr("x")
   });
}
```